# Get all email list of website. M2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I want all email list like order email, forgot password email, create account email, newsletter, shipment email, invoice email, refund email, other third party emails etc.....

How can i get all email list from website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Admin Panel You can get the all email templates :

```
Marketing > Communications > Email Templates
```